# php $_SERVER POST methods the new and more efficient style?

Tags: php, forms

i wrote a relatively simple but usable php query logging software a couple of years back and my setup was "plain vanilla" where a form, with a POST method has a separate page that processes the form like below

1) input form displays with a submit button that calls process-form.php
2) process-form.php then processes the form (e.g. enters the data onto a database)
3) process-form.php displays a message if everything is fine or not.

now, when i go through some php tutorials, they are teaching having the form submit upon itself by using $_SERVER

```
<?php
//use the $_SERVER function to decipher if the POST method has been triggered
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    //TODO: Send email, etc.
}
?>
```

i can see the benefits of of this method as the code remains compact as you just have to go to 1 page only instead of going to other pages if you need to fix something.  Is this the prevalent method now?  just asking as i am trying to learn.  thank you!

Comment: I don't use what you have written.  I use `if (count($_POST) > 0)`

Comment: be aware that some $_POST elements may not be set. Therefore, you would actually better use `$name = (isset($_POST['name'])?($_POST['name']):"");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isset()` or `sizeof()` or `empty()`

```
if (isset($_POST)) 
{
   $name = $_POST["name"];
   $email = $_POST["email"];
   $message = $_POST["message"];

   //TODO: Send email, etc.
}
```

**OR**

```
if (sizeof($_POST) > 0) 
{
   $name = $_POST["name"];
   $email = $_POST["email"];
   $message = $_POST["message"];

   //TODO: Send email, etc.
}
```

**OR**

```
if (!empty($_POST)) 
{
   $name = $_POST["name"];
   $email = $_POST["email"];
   $message = $_POST["message"];

   //TODO: Send email, etc.
}
```